# How does Vite recognize tsconfig.json and how to change it?

Tags: typescript, vite, tsconfig

I have a project with the custom builder based on Vite with the next structure:

```
builder
  index.ts
  tsconfig.json
application
  src
    server.ts
    ...
  index.html
  tsconfig.json
  ...
```

`builder/index.ts` contains something like that:

```
const root = '../application';
const viteConfig: InlineConfig[] = [
  // Compile SPA to get assets
  {
    root,
    build: {
      outDir: `${root}/dist`,
      ssrManifest: true,
      emptyOutDir: true,
      rollupOptions: {
        input: `${root}/index.html`,
      },
    },
  },
  // Compile SSR to transform then into SSG
  {
    root,
    build: {
      outDir: `${root}/dist/server`,
      ssr: true,
      rollupOptions: {
        input: `${root}/src/entryServer.ts`,
      },
    },
  },
];
```

Everything works fine, there are no errors and the result is what I want, but. I run `node index.ts` in cli, don't provide `tsconfig.json` path in configurations. How does Vite recognize, where it is? From `root`? I removed `application/tsconfig.json`, but it still working (have only errors in IDE). So I can't understand how Vite works with Typescript and how to provide the direct path to tsconfig

Comment: Maybe https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-tsconfig-paths can help you out.